# How to remove a folder mapping from a TFS workspace?

Tags: tfs, alm

I have a mapping to a folder in a TFS workspace:

$/Foo -> C:\Foo

one inner folder get the following mapping:

$/Foo/Bar -> C:\Foo\BAR

Is possible to remove the mapping of the "Bar"?

I do not want to remove the whole workspace (as many questions suggest).
I already try deleting the cache of the TFS in the machine.

Comment: No, you can't, as Ove said that using cloak feature is the better way.

Comment: What do you think of cloak feature for your requirement?

Comment: My requirement is to remove the mapping rather that avoid download the sources in the folder. I have a Third party that have a poor management of Caps in paths and it is looking for Bar folder, but it found BAR folder in the workspace mapping, therefore it fails. that is why i want to remove the folder mapping and then recreate it

Comment: You can't remove it, but you can change inner folder mapping to another folder, you can check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can’t remove the mapping, but you can add/change inner folder mapping to a different folder.

1. Open team explorer
2. Click Workspaces dropdown box > Workspaces
3. Select a workspace >Edit
4. Add an additional mapping for inner folder (e.g. $/Foo/Bar) to a different folder (e.g. C:/Bar).

Comment: I intent to have something like "No Mapping"

Answer (score 4):

You can use the cloak feature in tfs. Depending on the version of visual studio the right click menu is a bit different. In the later versions it is beneath the advanced when right clicking on a folder. You can also use the command line with tf cloak folder. This removes the disk usage of that folder and you can get latest on the top folder and it does not download the cloaked folder. I am using this to not download old release branches unless really needed ;)

Comment: Good solution. In VS2019, Source Control Explorer, then right-click the subfolder, select **Advanced->Cloak...**